# How do I cross validate when I don't have a test set?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

**Situation:** I have two models, fitted on the same data.

**Goal:** I want to meaure the out-of-sample performance of the two models.

**Problem**: I don't have a test set, and the original data is too small to split it up  into a batch for training and a batch for testing. So my only recourse is to simulate new test data... but say I bootstrap new data from my original data set. This is not really an "out-of-sample" data, since it's simulated via bootstrap from the data I fitted on! In fact, there's a non-zero chance that my "simulated test data" ... is **exactly the same as my original data**!

So what do I do?

Comment: Yeah, it's not a good idea to evaluate a model on test data generated from training data. The simulating-new-data idea tends to apply to training: split into training and test and simulate more training data from the training data you have (this may or may not work in your case).

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about your goal. "Measure the out-of-sample performance" doesn't seem like a research goal by itself - I guess you want to show one model is superior or find the best prediction model for a specific problem? This is relevant, because by simply picking the model with has the smaller out-of-sample error rate based on an estimate you end up with selection bias and overestimating the performance of the winner model. Also details about the sample size & model complexity could help give more useful answers.

Answer (score 7):

Since the dataset is small, you can estimate out-of-sample error/performance via leave-one-out cross validation, and compare LOOCV performances of the two models.

Note that, alongside the benefits, LOOCV has its cons as well: It's computationally more expensive, and it may have larger variance in the performance metric. But, this problem can be mitigated via calculating the performance after assigning all the class labels and calculating the performance for the whole set. Also, we won't have a single model in the end.

Comment: I'd say you still have a single model in the end: the one fit on the whole data. The ultimate purpose of k-fold cross validation is to estimate the accuracy of the model building process, not that of the k individual models.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Bayesian machine learning model. The distribution of your predictions shows you how accurate the model is. If your model overfits it will have a large variance in the predictions, because every model of the ensemble overfits differently. When you have enough data the distribution is very narrow and when you have infinite data equals the prediction of the non Bayesian model.

Every parameter of your model is now a distribution. Depending on the type of the model they can even be interpretable.

One easy way to obtain a Bayesian model is via Bayesian bootstrapping. You can either do that by training the model multiple times with different weights for each data point or by using a package like [bayesian_bootstrap](https://github.com/lmc2179/bayesian_bootstrap). The weights must be drawn from a Direchlet distribution (which in this case is a multivariate uniform distribution).